# Python - Selenium cannot press button on Eastleigh website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have made a script in Selenium which should access the Eastleigh website, it clicks "Advanced" types in the date from last week and press "Search" all of this works, EXCEPT it doesn't press "Search" button, why? The name variable in the website is called "submit" which is what my code is looking for but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\code\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    import urls.eastleigh
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\code\urls\eastleigh.py", line 48, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Code:

```
import sys
import time
import config
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver

print("1. Custom Date")
print("2. Last Week")
choice = input("#: ")
if choice == "1":
    print("Start Example: 1/8/2018")
    startDate = input("Start Date: ")
    print("Stop Example: 30/8/2018")
    stopDate = input("Stop Date: ")

elif choice == "2":
    sd = str(datetime.datetime.today().day) # Gets day of the month
    sm = str(datetime.datetime.today().month) # Gets month of the year
    sy = str(datetime.datetime.today().year) # Gets year
    nsd = int(sd) # Turns string variable "sd" into an integer
    startDate = "%s/%s/%s" % (nsd-7, sm, sy) # Makes a new date string. Minus 7 off of the original date to go back 1 week
    stopDate = "%s/%s/%s" % (nsd-1, sm, sy) # Makes a new date string. Minus 1 off of the original date, (Minusing 1 was Steve's idea, not mine.)
else:
    print("This is not a choice.")
    print("Press Enter to exit...")
    input("")
    sys.exit()

url = "https://planning.eastleigh.gov.uk/s/public-register"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("341:0__item").click()

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("728:0").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("728:0").send_keys(startDate)

driver.find_element_by_id("744:0").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("744:0").send_keys(stopDate)

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()

time.sleep(3)

result = []

#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='View More']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='View More']/ancestor::a[@class='slds-size--1-of-1 slds-text-align--right']")

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".slds-tile cLightningArticle a")
links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in elements]

result.extend(links)

for link in result:
    result.remove(link)
    driver.get(link)
    for i in range(1):
        div = driver.find_element_by_id("slds-form-element__group").text
        newDiv = div.replace("Reference ", "").replace("Alternative ", "").replace("Application Validated ", "").replace("Address ", "").replace("Proposal ", "").replace("Status ", "").replace("Decision ", "").replace("Issued Date ", "").replace("Appeal ", "")
        log = open("log.txt", "a")
        log.write(newDiv + "\n")
    log.write("\n")

#driver.close()
```

Comment: I don't see any of the IDs that you have in your script. Are you sure you are on the right page? Have you given us the right URL?

Comment: your 341:0__item is the id for Advanced Search thats fine.. but your 728:0 is for select dropdown not for any date picker..

Comment: What are you talking about? Literally everything does what it is needed to do. It just won't click search, if you run the script it'll do the rest for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two button tags with name="submit" in the DOM. Your target button is the second one. Try using the second index when you identify the 'Search' button.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@name='submit'])[2]")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much